# How to find out why a class is loaded

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, weblogic

One of our old projects is now moving from `poi-3.8` to `poi-5.2.0` to fix sonaType issues, but then, we encountered a weird problem. The application keeps loading a class (`org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList`) that did exist in 3.8 but no longer exist in 5.2.0, and cause `ClassNotFoundException` during **startup**.

### How we do upgrade

This package (poi) was originally introduced by another package provided by another team, and we did upgrade by excluding the old version and importing the new one in our pom.xml.

### After exception occurred

- We contacted the package provider and they suggested us remove classes that used `poi`. -> We did, but no helps.
- We enabled weblogic debug on classloader. -> We did get some *information*, but still no idea why it attemped to load that class, since the classes mentioned had no relationship with any of poi classes.

Here is the stacktrace and the context printed in weblogic logs:

```
Trigger: ClassNotFoundException
Trigger point: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:58)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1047)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1041)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:145)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.J2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(J2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:47)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.processJ2eeAnnotations(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:120)
  at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:93)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:304)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processPOJOsInModuleScopes(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:229)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.prepare(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:73)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
  at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
  at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:66)
  at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:229)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(StartOperation.java:95)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doPrepare(StartOperation.java:108)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
  at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
  at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
  at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
  at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
  at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
  at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
  at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
------------------------------------------------
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.141 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.140 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.139 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.139 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.138 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.138 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.137 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.137 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.defineClass(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.GenericRecord)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.134 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.GenericRecord)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.134 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.GenericRecord)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.133 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.GenericRecord)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.132 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.GenericRecord)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.129 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.util)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.129 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.util)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.128 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.util)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.127 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.defineClass(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.116 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.116 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.115 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.115 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.112 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.112 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.defineClass(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationHelper)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.108 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationHelper)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.107 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationHelper)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.107 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationHelper)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.106 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.loadClass(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationHelper)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.105 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(com.o.c.s.c.domain)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.105 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.defineClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.102 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.101 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.100 PM HKT> GCL[59c56c57][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.099 PM HKT> GCL[2b4500a9][Partition:DOMAIN] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.098 PM HKT> GCL[342782dd][System:Augmentable] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.097 PM HKT> GCL[2dde1bff][System:WebLogicExtension] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[2dde1bff][System:WebLogicExtension] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[2dde1bff][System:WebLogicExtension] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[342782dd][System:Augmentable] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[342782dd][System:Augmentable] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[2b4500a9][Partition:DOMAIN] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.094 PM HKT> GCL[2b4500a9][Partition:DOMAIN] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.093 PM HKT> GCL[59c56c57][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.093 PM HKT> GCL[59c56c57][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.093 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.093 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.loadClass(com.o.c.s.c.domain.C_omit_n)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.091 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.getPackage(com.o.c.l.w.domain)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.090 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.defineClass(com.o.c.l.w.domain.L_omit_S)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.087 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.l.w.domain.L_omit_S)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.087 PM HKT> CACL[639bf5df][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@rpt] CACL.findClass(com.o.c.l.w.domain.L_omit_S)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.085 PM HKT> GCL[59c56c57][WLS_R_F_ear-1.0.294@] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.l.w.domain.L_omit_S)
<Jul 21, 2022 05:53:11.084 PM HKT> GCL[2b4500a9][Partition:DOMAIN] GCL.findClass(com.o.c.l.w.domain.L_omit_S)
```

So I'm here to seek for some help on how it happened, how I should analyze the log or maybe some other tools that can look into the dependency relationship in a clearer way.

Comment: I think you are mis-reading this stacktrace.  Are not missing some lines above this error?

Comment: I would consider this to be a support issue for the _other_ team as it is their package and it is a blocker.

Comment: Hi @ScaryWombat , there are almost everything in debug log, lines above are just time, thread name, etc...

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , we have been in contact with provider team, Thanks.